# Why does my prometheus dashboard only show 2 weeks of data when I have longer term data available?

Tags: monitoring, metrics, prometheus, thanos

I have Prometheus configured with Thanos. I'm using the [Node Exporter Full](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/1860) dashboard to view data from the node exporter. Regardless of what time range I select (e.g., `now-20d`), the dashboard only shows 2 weeks of data:

[image]

If I go to the "Explore" UI instead and entry a query (such as `node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance="172.31.64.1:9100", job="node"}`, which matches the data shown in the previous image), using the same data source and time range, I obviously have data going back much farther:

[image]

What is preventing the dashboard from showing data beyond the last two weeks?

Answer (score 0):

The default Prometheus retention time is 15 days.

From https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#operational-aspects:

> Prometheus has several flags that configure local storage. The most important are:
> ...
> `--storage.tsdb.retention.time`: When to remove old data. Defaults to 15d. Overrides storage.tsdb.retention if this flag is set to anything other than default.

Retention can also be configured based on size:

> `--storage.tsdb.retention.size`: The maximum number of bytes of storage blocks to retain. The oldest data will be removed first. Defaults to 0 or disabled. Units supported: B, KB, MB, GB, TB, PB, EB. Ex: "512MB"...

You can view your current retention setting on a running Prometheus instance by going to `http://<IP_address_of_instance>:9090/status` and looking for the "Storage retention" line.

Comment: The data is coming from Thanos, not from Prometheus, and as noted in the question Thanos demonstrably has more than two weeks of retained data.